# ¿Comparar datos $lookup Mongo DB?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Hola soy nuevo en mongo y estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me regrese los temas vistos por el usuario, estos son los `schemas` que tengo:

`Schema` del Bloque

```
    const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
    
    const blockSchema = new Schema(
     {
       blockTitle: String,
       idCourse: {
         type: Schema.ObjectId,
         ref: "course",
       },
       preference: Number
     },{ timestamps: true, });
    
    module.exports = model("block", blockSchema);
    Schema del tema
    
    const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose');
    
    const topicSchema = new Schema({
       topicTitle: String,
       preference: Number,
       keyTopicVideo: String,
       resources: [{
          title: String,
          keyDownloadResource: String,
          urlDownloadResource: String,
          urlExtern: String
      }],
      idBlock: {
          type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: 'block'
      }
    },{
        timestamps: true,
      });
    
    module.exports = model('topic',topicSchema);

Schema del tema completado

    const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
    
    const topicsCompletedSchema = new Schema({
      idTopic: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "topic",
      },
      idUser: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
      },
      idCourse: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "course",
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
    );
    
    module.exports = model("topicsCompleted", topicsCompletedSchema);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es comparar es que si ya hay un registro en el esquema de tema completado ahora y ese tema tenga el `idUser` del usuario a buscar me retorne un campo con la información del tema completado, este es el código que tengo en la ruta :

```
    courseCtrl.getListCourse = async (req,res) => {
      try {
        await modelBlock.find({idCourse: req.params.idCourse} , async function (err, GroupBlocks){
        const listCourseAdmin = [];
          for(i = 0; i < GroupBlocks.length; i++){
            const topics =  await modelTopic.aggregate([
               {
                 $sort : { preference: 1 }
               },
               {
                 $match: {
                   $or: [ { idBlock: GroupBlocks[i]._id } ]
                 }
               },
               {
                 $lookup: {
                   from: 'topicsCompleted',
                   let: { "id": "$_id" , "user" : "5fe24332540d0226347b720e"},
                   pipeline: [
                     {
                       $match: {
                         $expr: {
                           $and: [
                             { $eq: ["$idTopic","$$id"] },
                             { $eq: ["$idUser","$$user"] }
                           ] 
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   ],
                   as: 'topicCompleted'
                 }
               }
             ],
             async function(err, subCategoriasBase) {
               return subCategoriasBase;
             }
           );
         listCourseAdmin.push({
           block: GroupBlocks[i],
           topics: topics
         });
       }  
       res.status(200).json(listCourseAdmin);
     })
    } catch (error) {
       res.status(505).json({ message: "Error del servidor", error });
       console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

Aquí trato de traerme los temas del bloque y en ese tema si el usuario ya hizo ese tema, pero el campo del tema complete me retorna vacío:

```
    {
        "block": {
            "_id": "5ffccf964415d4402c307e3a",
            "blockTitle": "fggfgfgffg",
            "idCourse": "5ff373f24dbbca325092db1c",
            "createdAt": "2021-01-11T22:22:14.356Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-01-11T23:28:01.890Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "topics": [
            {
                "_id": "5ffce13100d9274594114921",
                "topicTitle": "Tema uno",
                "idBlock": "5ffccf964415d4402c307e3a",
                "preference": 1,
                "createdAt": "2021-01-11T23:37:21.478Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-01-13T22:15:22.253Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "keyTopicVideo": "345465453423",
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5ffdf559a8aac436244a737f",
                        "title": "wewewewe",
                        "urlDownloadResource": "https://urlImagen"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5ffdf688adea48393018d584",
                        "title": "wewewewe",
                        "urlExtern": "sdsdsdsdsd"
                    }
                ],
                "topicCompleted": []
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fff3e8f49b4aa0c208a5183",
                "topicTitle": "Tema dos",
                "idBlock": "5ffccf964415d4402c307e3a",
                "preference": 2,
                "resources": [],
                "createdAt": "2021-01-13T18:40:15.213Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-01-13T18:40:15.213Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "topicCompleted": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

y tengo un registro existente con el id del tema `5ffce13100d9274594114921` y el id del usuario `5fe24332540d0226347b720e` que estoy comparando, no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal espero puedan ayudarme.

Registro de tema completado

```
    {
      "_id": {"$oid":"6001dc0caaa4c22a54e26117"},
      "idTopic":{"$oid":"5ffce13100d9274594114921"},
      "idUser":{"$oid":"5fe24332540d0226347b720e"},
      "idCourse":{"$oid":"5ff373f24dbbca325092db1c"},
      "createdAt":{"$date":"2021-01-15T18:16:44.751Z"},
      "updatedAt":{"$date":"2021-01-15T18:16:44.751Z"},
      "__v":0
    }
```

Esta consulta en `SQL` me regresa los temas del bloque y si el usuario ya hizo ese tema me marca 1 en caso contrario 0 en el campo `temas_vistos`

```
    SELECT a.idtema,a.nombre,a.descripcion,a.video,a.archivo,case when b.tema is null then 0 else 1 end 
    as temas_vistos FROM tema a LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tema_completado tm WHERE tm.usuario = ?) b on 
    a.idtema = b.tema INNER JOIN bloque c ON c.idbloque = a.bloque WHERE a.bloque = ? AND c.curso = ? 
    ORDER BY preferencia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421056/comparar-datos-lookup-mongo-db#comment753561_421100), tu problema está en que mezclas el concepto de [Modelo](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) con el concepto de [Modelo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) de [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/). Y lamentablemente son cosas muy diferentes en su implementación.

Sin entrar mucho en detalles, un Modelo de Datos de MongoDB es básicamente la forma en que se organiza la información en documentos BSON almacenados en colecciones. En cambio en Mongoose, un Modelo de Datos es una representación de un Esquema, con ciertas propiedades y características propias del ODM donde fueron creados, en este caso Mongoose. Si bien existe una relación muy estrecha entre esta representación y el documento almacenado en la base de datos, hay características que no se replican desde Mongoose hacia MongoDB, como por ejemplo las referencias.

De la documentación de Mongoose sobre el método `populate()` se desprende lo siguiente: (traducción propia, negrillas agregadas por mi)

> MongoDB tiene un operador de agregación parecido a un *join* llamado `$lookup`, disponible a partir de la versión >= 3.2 (de MongoDB). Mongoose tiene una **alternativa** más potente llamada `populate()`, la cual le permite crear referencias a documentos en otras colecciones.

En Mongoose una [referencia](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs) se establece o se guarda sobre un campo cuyo tipo de valor es [`ObjectID`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids). Mongoose saca provecho de este tipo de referencias a otros documentos, usando una propiedad llamada `ref` para dicho campo. El valor de `ref` es el nombre de un **Modelo de Mongoose** previamente instanciado para dicha conexión. Esta propiedad (`ref`) es la que le indica a Mongoose a qué Modelo pertenece dicho valor de `ObjectId`.

En MongoDB no existe tal propiedad `ref` sobre un campo de un documento, de hecho no existe la estructura creada por Mongoose para la representación de un campo en un documento. Y aunque se puede hablar de Esquemas y Modelo de Datos en MongoDB, no se refieren a las estructuras, clases y objetos que tiene Mongoose. Sin embargo, en MongoDB si que tenemos la posibilidad de crear [referencias](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/), ya sean [manuales](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references) (directas) o mediante objetos [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation). En la documentación de MongoDB se recomienda usar sólo referencias manuales y evitar usar objetos DBRefs siempre que sea posible. La diferencia radica en que un objeto `DBref` de MongoDB suele usarse en documentos de diferentes colecciones para apuntar a documentos de una misma colección. Cierto que el formato **se parece** al de Mongoose, un objeto DBRef en MongoDB se ve así:

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5126bbf64aed4daf9e2ab771"),
  // .. application fields
  "creator" : {
                  "$ref" : "creators",
                  "$id" : ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"),
                  "$db" : "users"
               }
}
```

Y bien podríamos pensar que es prácticamente lo mismo que se hace en Mongoose, sin embargo, cuando se almacena un documento con un campo con una referencia creada en Mongoose, el mismo no tendrá la estructura de un objeto DBRef, sino que sería algo más simple:

```js
// Documento almacenado usando la propiedad `ref` en Mongoose:
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5126bbf64aed4daf9e2ab771"),
  // .. application fields
  "creator" :  ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"),

}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una de las soluciones es simplemente usar el nombre de la colección que almacena los documentos del esquema `topicsCompleted` en el campo `from` de tu etapa `$lookup` de agregación:

```
from: 'topicsCompleted', // <- debe ser el nombre de la colección.
```

Y por lo que muestras en tu código estás usando el nombre del Modelo de datos creado en Mongoose.

El asunto está en que Mongoose no realiza la agregación, aunque el llamado lo hagas en el Modelo de Mongoose. Quien realiza la agregación es MongoDB. El driver de MongoDB de NodeJS recibe la agregación tal como se la pasa Mongoose y a su vez envía el comando a la Base de Datos. Es MongoDB quien se encarga de realizar la agregación y devolver un resultado.

Aclarado este punto, una de las cosas que puedes hacer es establecer manualmente el nombre de la colección que será usada en MongoDB, al momento de crear tu esquema. Por ejemplo:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const topicsCompletedSchema = new Schema(
  {
    idTopic: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "topic"
    },
    // ...
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    collection: "topicsCompleted" // <- estableces el nombre de la colección
  }
);

module.exports = model("topicsCompleted", topicsCompletedSchema);
```

De esta forma, esta linea en la etapa de agregación ahora sí que tendría sentido:

```
from: 'topicsCompleted',
```

ya que la colección `topicsCompleted` existirá ya que es el nombre que le has asignado para almacenar los documentos del tipo `topicsCompleted`.

MongoDB no cambia los nombres de las colecciones, lo hace Mongoose. Mediante una herramienta utilitaria llamada [`pluralize`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection). Traduciendo la documentación:

> Mongoose por defecto, establece el nombre de la colección pasando el nombre del modelo al método `utils.toCollectionName`. Este método pluraliza el nombre. Debes establecer esta opción si necesitas un nombre diferente para tu colección.

Como el nombre de tu modelo de datos es `topicsCompleted`, al no establecer la opción `collection` en tu esquema de datos, Mongoose automáticamente le agrega una letra `s` al nombre del modelo de datos para establecer el nombre de la colección.

Con este pequeño cambio el proceso de agregación funcionará sin problemas.

Espero que esto te ayude a comprender un poco mejor la diferencia que existe entre los campos referenciados en un esquema de Mongoose con las referencias establecidas en un proceso de agregación mediante `$lookup`. Siendo que uno apunta a un Modelo de Mongoose, para poder usar `populate` y el otro apunta a una colección en MongoDB, donde no existe la noción de referencia que se establece en Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

En los esquemas mostrados, se están declarando las llaves `idTopic/idUser` como `ObjectID`:

```
      idTopic: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "topic",
      },
      idUser: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
      },
      idCourse: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "course",
      },
```

En el código que nos compartes, en la colección topics, el `_id` es un tipo `String`:

```
 "topics": [
            {
                "_id": "5ffce13100d9274594114921",//tipo string
                "topicTitle": "Tema uno",
                ...mas datos
```

Entonces, los datos `user` y `_id` que se pasan en la sección `let` del stage `$lookup`, son de tipo `String`:

```
let: { "id": "$_id" , "user" : "5fe24332540d0226347b720e"}
```

Pero, en el registro del tema completado, aparecen como `ObjectId`:

```
{
      "_id": {"$oid":"6001dc0caaa4c22a54e26117"},
      "idTopic":{"$oid":"5ffce13100d9274594114921"},
      "idUser":{"$oid":"5fe24332540d0226347b720e"},
      "idCourse":{"$oid":"5ff373f24dbbca325092db1c"},
      "createdAt":{"$date":"2021-01-15T18:16:44.751Z"},
      "updatedAt":{"$date":"2021-01-15T18:16:44.751Z"},
      "__v":0
    }
```

Por lo tanto, en la sección `pipeline` del stage `$lookup` se está realizando una comparación `ObjectId` vs `String`, para ambas llaves:

```
$and: [
              { $eq: ["$idTopic","$$id"] },
              { $eq: ["$idUser","$$user"] }
]
```

Ahora, dicho lo anterior, al emular el ejemplo tal cual lo presentas, ya tienes todo el aggregation pipeline codificado correctamente, solo falta [**comparar de forma correcta los tipos de datos**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/), cuando se hace el `pipeline` del stage `$lookup`:

```
  pipeline: [
             {
               $match: {
                 $expr: {
                   $and: [
                     { $eq: ["$idTopic", {$toObjectId: "$$id"}]},
                     { $eq: ["$idUser", {$toObjectId: "$$user"}] }
                   ] 
                 }
               }
             }
           ],
           as: 'topicCompleted'
  }
```

Aqui, una imágen de la salida que obtuve, ya con el ajuste de comparación de tipos que mencioné:
[image: salida con datos de prueba para $lookup/left outter join]

Por último, hay que verificar cual es el tipo de dato para la llave `_id` en la colección `topics`, y tambien el tipo de dato que se pasa en `user` dentro de `let`; en los datos que compartes son `String`, pero puede que esten como `ObjectID` en tu BDD, pues **MongoDB** inserta una llave `_id` como tipo `ObjectId`, si esta llave no es especificada por el códificador.

Por lo tanto, si la llave `_id` de la colleción `topics` es de tipo `ObjectId` en tu BDD, entonces solo se tendría que validar el tipo para `user`, en la sección pipeline del stage `$lookup`, asumiendo que `user` se va a seguir pasando como tipo `String`:

```
$and: [
              { $eq: ["$idTopic","$$id"] },
              { $eq: ["$idUser",{$toObjectId: "$$user"] }
]
```

Espero que este análisis sea de ayuda.

Comment: Ahh ok entiendo, si el _id del schema topic si es tipo ObjectId, como dices solo me faltaria convertir la variable user a ObjectId, lo hize y me siguio dando el mismo problema, sigue sin retornar nada en el topicComplete :(

Comment: La idea es pasar el user del let por la url de la ruta, asi podra traerme los bloques y temas del bloque mas los temas vistos por el usuario, pero no funciona :,(

Comment: Bueno, ya sabemos que en BDD para la colección `topicsCompleted`, `idTopic` y `idUser` son `ObjectId`. Lo que yo haría primero, es verificar con `typeof` que datos estoy usando en el aggregation para `user` y `_id`, es hay donde yo probaría con diferentes combinaciones, en la sección pipeline del `$lookup`, estoy seguro que el problema esta en esa sección de tu aggregation. Otra cosa que podrías probar, es declarar en tus esquemas, todos los `id` involucrados en tu búsqueda como tipo `String`, borrar y reinsertar todos los registros nuevamente y ver qué sucede.

Comment: Si, ya cambie el parametro del $and a $or para ver si alguna de las dos condiciones con el $eq funcionaba, pero al parecer ninguna se esta cumpliendo, estoy mirando porque, porque solo una es String el user del let y las otra son ObjectId, seguire investigando a ver si encuestro la solucion, igual muchas gracias :)

Comment: Es un caso interesante, la analogía que nos mostraste del `left outter join` de **SQL** y el `$lookup` de mongoDB, ojalá puedas compartirnos la solución, si consideras que la respuesta fue de ayuda, puedes votar, suerte y salud!

Comment: Ya encontre el error, al parecer yo estaba referenciando al schema de tema completado en el lookup como "topicsComplete" cuando mongo al crear el schema le agrega una "s" y cambia todo a minusculas, por lo que la referecia correcta era "topicscompleteds", ya con esto funciono correctamente, te agradezco la ayuda :)

Comment: Interesante, no sabía lo del cambio de nombre durante la creación de esquema, buena información documentada!

Comment: Mongo no cambia el nombre de la colección, lo hace Mongoose. Una cosa es la referencia creada sobre un esquema y otra muy distinta el uso de `$lookup` sobre un modelo de datos. En Mongoose puedes crear referencias para usarlas luego en una consulta (`query`) usando `populate`. Sin embargo, dicha referencia sólo existe en el Modelo de datos (un Objeto de Mongoose no de Mongo). Un `lookup` no puede aprovechar esa referencia, porque en Mongo no existe ese Modelo de datos. No confundas Mongoose con MongoDB. Saludos

Comment: Interesante @MauricioContreras, con esta explicación y tu respuesta ya queda despejada toda duda para este tipo de casos, saludos.

Comment: Wow interesante @MauricioContreras si, ese era mi error que referenciaba al modelo y no al schema creado ya, ahora todo queda claro :)